# AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'post_image'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF and Django(4.0) to make posts in a Instagram Clone. The models of the following are available below. I have successfully implemented post request, but am having problems implementing get request.

I have tried to nest two serializer inside the PostViewSerializer to serialize the data. However I am getting the following error when I do a get request.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'post_image' on serializer 'PostViewSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'post_image'.
```

Now, I should tell you that there is not requirement that the post should contain atleast one image or video it could contain entirely either videos or posts. So, could that be the cause of the above error. If so, how can I solve it?

```
#models.py
class Post(Authorable, Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    caption = TextField(max_length=350)

class Images(Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

class Videos(Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    videos = models.FileField(upload_to="videos/")
```

```
#behaviours.py
class Authorable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    def get_user(self):
        return self.user.id
```

```
#serializers.py
class ImageViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ['images']

class VideoViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Videos
        fields = [ 'videos']

class PostViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_image = ImageViewSerializer()
    post_video = VideoViewSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_image', 'post_video', 'caption','user']

class PostUpload(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        serializer = PostViewSerializer(Post.objects.filter(user=user), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Edit 1:(With Full Traceback Error)**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/post/

Django Version: 4.0
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
 'core',
 'authentication',
 'socialuser']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 457, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 97, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)

During handling of the above exception ('Post' object has no attribute 'images'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\Desktop\Memestagram\socialuser\views.py", line 22, in get
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 768, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
    return [
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 687, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 490, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/user/post/
Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `post_image` on serializer `PostViewSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'images'.
```

My Serializer

```
class PostViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #           access ForeignKey in reverse 
    post_image = ImageViewSerializer(source='images', many=True)
    post_video = VideoViewSerializer(source='videos', many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_image', 'post_video', 'caption','user']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ImageField`, `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, etc. with `post_image` as name. You can access the images with `.images`. This thus means that you use this as source:

```
class PostViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #           access ForeignKey in reverse 🖟
    post_image = ImageViewSerializer(source='images_set', many=True)
    post_video = VideoViewSerializer(source='videos_set', many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_image', 'post_video', 'caption','user']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even after implementing the above code. I am getting the exact same error.

Comment: @GuruRandapa: can you edit the question and share the full traceback?

Comment: I have edited the question. :-)

Comment: @GuruRandapa: are you sure you've set the `source=...` parameter and restarted the server?

Comment: I have updated the traceback error it was before I updated the serializer but it I think its the same... and I have mentioned what serializer I am using currently. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: @GuruRandapa: I made an error, it is `images_set` and `videos_set`.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! It worked... I will read more on the topic and will try to understand it better.